# Yasgui SPARQL Query search for FOAF name doesn't work

Tags: sparql

I am using the Jamendo Yasgui SPARQL query to search for artist names. It works like this:

```sql
 PREFIX mo: <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/>
 PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 SELECT * WHERE {?a a mo:MusicArtist ;foaf:name ?name;}
```

If I want to find a specific name like below, it does not work. Why?

```sql
PREFIX mo: <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/>
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
SELECT * WHERE {?a a mo:MusicArtist ;foaf:name "Carton";}
```

The data exists as you can see in the RDF/XML:

```xml
<foaf:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Carton</foaf:name>
```

Comment: ok, but you also see the datatype in your RDF/XML example...you have to use the given datatypes for the literals in RDF as SPARQL is exact pattern matching. `PREFIX mo: <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/>
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
SELECT * WHERE {?a a mo:MusicArtist ;foaf:name "Carton"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>}`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am new to Sparql and there is still a lot i dont understand. Based on introduction the following code should work, since foaf:based_near is connected to geonames. But it does not work. Do you know why? `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX gn: <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?a ?place ?geo {
  ?a foaf:name ?name.
  ?a foaf:based_near ?place.
    ?place gn:name ?geo.
} 
ORDER BY ?geo`

Comment: what do you expect to get about the place? It doesn't work because the data does not exist or better said isn't loaded into the triple store (aka database) that you use. Which tutorial told you that it should work?

Comment: Under point 4 here: http://dbtune.org/jamendo/ In the xml data there is a geolocation URI for each foaf:based_near property. Shouldnt i been able to then find also the label of that geolocation? If not, i dont understand the concept of linked data.

Comment: Ok, but the page might be outdated or just wrong. You can check that there is no such data about the places by using `SELECT *
WHERE
{ ?s
     <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/based_near> ?place . ?place ?p ?o
  }
limit 10`

Comment: Ok, i have this now, which works: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX gn: <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?a ?k {
  ?a foaf:based_near <http://sws.geonames.org/2802361/>.
  ?a foaf:based_near ?k.
} ` For example i cannot add now the population of that based_near country, since that information is not in the database of jamendo? Therefore jamendo and geonames database are not linked? Are there sparql query sites, where i can use all databases?

Comment: I don't know about public triple stores holding both datasets. But, both are not that big so you can easily load both datasets into a local triple store.

Answer (score 1):

Because SPARQL syntax was built to look like Turtle syntax (and vice versa), it's often helpful to look at your data in Turtle when building SPARQL queries.  This RDF/XML --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF><rdf:RDF xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:ns1="http://purl.org/ontology/mo/" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
<ns1:MusicArtist rdf:about="http://dbtune.org/jamendo/artist/5655">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource"/>
  <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://zitgist.com/music/artist/b8b40a3c-91c0-413b-a4f9-194ef0c7151a"/>
  <foaf:based_near rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/2802361/"/>
  <foaf:homepage rdf:resource="http://cartonpate.com"/>
  <foaf:img rdf:resource="http://img.jamendo.com/artists/c/carton.jpg"/>
  <foaf:made rdf:resource="http://dbtune.org/jamendo/record/4957"/>
  <foaf:name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Carton</foaf:name>
</ns1:MusicArtist>

</rdf:RDF>
```

-- says the same thing as this Turtle --

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
PREFIX  owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
PREFIX  xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://dbtune.org/jamendo/artist/5655>
   a               <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/MusicArtist>, 
                   rdfs:Resource ;
   owl:sameAs      <http://zitgist.com/music/artist/b8b40a3c-91c0-413b-a4f9-194ef0c7151a> ;
   foaf:based_near <http://sws.geonames.org/2802361/> ;
   foaf:homepage   <http://cartonpate.com> ;
   foaf:img        <http://img.jamendo.com/artists/c/carton.jpg> ;
   foaf:made       <http://dbtune.org/jamendo/record/4957> ;
   foaf:name       "Carton"^^xsd:string .
```

-- so your SPARQL query must be (modulo whitespaces, each of which may be reduced to a single space) --

```
PREFIX   mo: <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX  rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX  xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 

SELECT * WHERE { ?a a         mo:MusicArtist ;
                    foaf:name "Carton"^^xsd:string }
```